# Формула принадлежности пикселя фракталу

Tags: фракталы

Экспериментирую с построением  геометрических фракталов.
Суть построения похоже на кривую Леви
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кривая_Леви](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8)
Только  вместо того чтобы  брать постоянный угол поворота средней точки 1.57 рад берется последовательно целый набор углов и рисуют не отрезки а только точки.

0 итерация, красные точки, старт.

1 итерация, зеленая точка

2 итерация, синие точки

3 итерация, фиолетовые точки

Кривая Леви, 3 итерации,

итерация1  углы ang1

итерация2  углы ang1 ang1

итерация3  углы ang1 ang1 ang1 ang1

[image: Кривая Леви, 3 итерации]

На каждой новой  итерации читается  последовательность углов.
Фрактал, 3 итерации,

итерация1  углы ang1

итерация2  углы ang1 ang2

итерация3  углы ang1 ang2 ang3 ang4

На каждой новой итерации  последовательность углов читается  заново.

[image: Фрактал, 3 итерации]

Суть отрисовки такого фрактала это подсчет количества попаданий в пиксель изображения. Например задаем растр 500 на 500 пикселей, считаем такой фрактал округляя координаты каждой точки до координат пикселя. В какой пиксель попали туда добавляем единицу.
В итоге получаем массив  500 на 500 в каждой ячейке сколько раз попали в пиксель. Дальше преобразуем количество попаданий в цвет, больше попаданий больше яркость.

Если взять 19 итераций фрактала и чередовать 4 угла можно получить такое.
[image: 19 итераций фрактала и чередовать 4 угла]

Тут можно придумать еще много разных правил чтения углов как хватит фантазии. Сейчас хочу попробовать усложнить форму рисуя штук 50 таких фракталов сразу, на процессоре это считать долго  т.к. будут  миллионы точек, а хотелось бы в реальном времени поэтому хочу попробовать сделать на шейдерах OpenGL. Шейдеры очень любят распаралеленые  задачи поэтому им удобна  была бы формула не считающая последовательно 19 итераций, а некая формула отвечающая  сразу сколько раз такой фрактал попадает в  текущий пиксель экрана. Пусть формула даже будет сложной, всеравно по идее будет считать намного быстрей видеокарта чем процессор.

Вот вопрос больше по математике, как придумать такую формулу? Это вообще возможно? Может есть некое приближенное решение?
Может есть формулы  для кривой Леви сколько раз пиксель принадлежит кривой и на основе этой идеи можно будет что-то придумать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В смысле 50 разных фракталов одновременно, с разными углами-правилами или 50 одинаковых? Не совсем понятно.

Comment: 50 разных фракталов. По формуле идеи есть?